# Cambiar el valor de un campo condicionado al valor de otros dos en PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Soy principiante en SQL y tengo una tabla en la que deseo cambiar el valor de un campo si se da la combinación de dos valores en otros dos campos vs dos valores en otros dos campos con un campo en común. Seria algo como:

```
IF "CAMPO 1" AND "CAMPO 2" = "CAMPO 1" AND "CAMPO 3" THEN
   UPDATE "TABLA"
   SET "CAMPO 2" = '';
```

Gracias

Comment: Te has saltado todos los protocolos de [so] para formular una pregunta. Recuerda incluir siempre: qué tengo, qué quiero y qué he intentado. Bienvenido a [so] y mírate [ask]

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si la respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 1):

Quieres decir algo así:

```
UPDATE tabla set campo2=''
  WHERE campo1=campo2 AND campo2=campo3;
```

Según el manual:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-update.html

Deberías empezar por realizar una consulta de selección que cumpla las condiciones que buscas:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla
  WHERE campo1=campo2 AND campo2=campo3;
```

Y, entonces, ya puedes sustituir `SELECT * FROM` por `UPDATE` y añadir el `SET` para fijar los valores que quieras actualizar. Ten en cuenta que un `UPDATE` sin `WHERE` cambia TODOS los registros de ese campo en toda la tabla.

Es una precaución similar al `DELETE` con el `WHERE`. Haciéndolo así, nunca se te olvidará.

Lo que has intentado tiene lógica de lenguaje de programación, buen intento. Las bases de datos funcionan diferente.

Comment: si bien el enlace puede tener información que aplique de manera indistinta, recuerda que el OP indica en las tags usar `PostgreSQL` y no `MySQL` te recomiendo darle fuentes relacionadas a la herramienta

Comment: ¡Gracias @alfap! Si es que ya no son horas, menudo despiste... :) Arreglado